# MySQL Group by Sum Total

Tags: mysql, database

I'm getting an error when trying to group by a sum value.

```
select sum(price  + adjustments) as adjusted_price from items group by adjusted_price
```

Is this not possible?

Example: I want to grab items that have the same adjusted price. Example ( $1.00 - .50 = .50)  --- ( $2.00 - 1.50 = .50), I want to grab items that have .50 grouped together.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? It does not make sense

Comment: No. It's not. Explain what you want to do. Example data and expected output may help

Comment: The group by doesn't make any sense to me there.

Comment: I want to grab items that have the same adjusted price. Example ( $1.00 - .50 = .50)  --- ( $2.00 - 1.50 = .50), I want to grab items that have .50 grouped together.

Comment: Example data and expected output please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for the grand total `adjusted_price`?  If so you don't need the `groupby`

```
select
  sum(adjusted_price)
from 
  (select price+adjustments as adjusted_price from items) tt
```

Edit:

Sounds like you want to group by the `adjusted_price`.  Try the following which will return the frequency count as well:

```
select
  adjusted_price, count(1)
from 
  (select price+adjustments as adjusted_price from items) tt
group by adjusted_price
```

Or the following should get you only the unique `adjusted_price` values:

```
select distinct
  adjusted_price
from 
  (select price+adjustments as adjusted_price from items) tt
```

Answer (score -1):

> Is this not possible?

Forget about possibility, moreover that looks wrong and incorrect. Why you are trying to `group by` the `SUM()` result BTW? You should rather `group by` any other column in your table. something like below but can't say for sure unless see your table schema and sample data.

```
select sum(price)  + sum(adjustments) as adjusted_price 
from items 
group by some_column_name;
```

Comment: I edited my question to be reflect on what I'm looking for. - Thank you

Comment: @BrianG, yes saw it and it doesn't make any difference. post your table schema along with sample data if further help needed.